# Detecting what platform code is running on in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, cross-platform

I have C# code I want to use in both a WinForms app and ASP.NET website. The database connection string differs for each though, so I want to be able to find out which platform it's running on and set the connection string appropriately. Is there an easy/recommended way to do this ?

This should compile on both WinForms and ASP.NET, so nothing that needs either a `System.Windows` or `System.Web` reference please.

Comment: how about writing a common service layer so that both winforms app. and ASP.NET 'talk' to the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to store the connection string in a configuration file - either App.Config or Web.Config, and use the `ConfigurationManager` to read from that.  See [Storing and Retrieving Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

The framework already handles this for you. Use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` or `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to read your connection strings and they will be read from **App.config** in WinForms and from **Web.config** in ASP.NET. You can put different values in the two config files.

As for the more general question - you could check `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` and if it's not `null` you're definitely running inside ASP.NET. If it's `null` you're *probably* not in ASP.NET, but may just not be inside a request. You could also try checking some of the properties on `System.Web.HttpRuntime`.

**Edit:** If you don't want to add a reference to System.Web.dll you could call the above via Reflection: first call `Type.GetType("System.Web.HttpContex")` and if that returns `null` then you're definitely not in ASP.NET. If it returns a value you can then proceed to get the `Current` static property on it.

Comment: I want to use the same code for both though (easier maintenance), and a reference to System.Web.HttpContext.Current won't compile in a WinForms app. Thanks for the config files suggestion though.

Comment: We do something similar to Evgeny suggestion of checking to see if system.WEb.HttpContext.Current exists in one of our custom dll and it works great. Maybe seperate the code that checks to see if it's a web/forms app in a different project (and add the system.web referene there?)

Comment: That works, thanks for your help. Sorry I can only accept one answer!

Answer (score 1):

Having the database code detecting the platform it's running on seems like the wrong solution.  No matter what you choose it seems like there would be a way to beat it.

Instead I would have the entry point of my application express it's platform declaratively.

```
enum Platform {
  AspNet,
  WinForms
}

public class DataConnection {
  public DataConnection(Platform platform) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite new to ASP.NET, what would be the "entry point of my application" to declare Platform in ? I'm assuming it would be Program.cs for WinForms.